# How do I make the second div have the same height as first div, irrespective of the screen-width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my two divs to be of equal height regardless of the device used to view the page. To ensure this, I wrote the js function below:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var left=document.getElementsByClassName('bg-text')[0].clientHeight;
    var right=document.getElementsByClassName('para')[0].clientHeight;
    if(left>right) {
        document.getElementsByClassName('para')[0].style.height=left+"px";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementsByClassName('bg-text')[0].style.height=right+"px";
    }
};
```

The code above works for most cases, not all. As I keep on reducing the screen width from the console, the second div becomes larger than the first div. How do I fix this?

**EDIT: ** This is my html:

```
<div class="bg-text">
        <h4><u>Newspaper particulars</u></h4><br>
        <ul>
            <li><label for="date">Select date :</label><br></li>
            <input type="date" id="date" name="date" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;"><br><br>
            <li><label for="news">Select newspaper :</label><br></li>
            <select name="news" id="news" style="text-align: center; width: 100%;">
                <option value="default">Click to select</option>
                <option value="The Assam Tribune">The Assam Tribune</option>
                <option value="The Times of India">The Times of India</option>
                <option value="The Hindu">The Hindu</option>
                <option value="Hindustan Times">Hindustan Times</option>
                <option value="The Telegraph">The Telegraph</option>
            </select><br><br>
            <li><label for="paragraph_text" id="para">Subject description :</label><br></li>
                <textarea name="paragraph_text" id="paragraph_text" rows="3" style="resize: none; box-sizing:border-box; width: 100%; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box;"></textarea><br><br>
            <span>Choose the required mode of input</span>
            <li><div class="mb-3" style="width: 100%; border: 2px solid white; padding: 10px;">
                <input type="radio" id="sel_scan" name="doc" value="scanning">
                <button id="scan" onclick="startScan()" disabled>Scan document</button><br><br>
                <div style="width: 100%;"> 
                    <input type="radio" id="myfile" name="doc" value="choosing">
                    <input type="file" id="Myfile"  accept=".pdf,.jpg,.png" disabled>
                </div>
            </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="para">
        <div class="container">
            <span id="preview_text" style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; line-height: 400px; color: red;">Choose/Scan file to see preview here</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want both the divs `bg-text` and `para` be of equal heights. Infact, as the second div is empty, so I want it to be the same height as that of the first div

Comment: can you share the html/css ([mcve])?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust the heights on resize as well. The code below should work:

```
function setHeight() {
  var leftElement = document.getElementsByClassName('bg-text')[0];
  var rightElement = document.getElementsByClassName('para')[0];
  // Reset height
  leftElement.style.height = "auto";
  rightElement.style.height = "auto";
  var leftHeight = leftElement.offsetHeight;
  var rightHeight = rightElement.offsetHeight;
  // Get max height and set it for both divs
  var maxHeight = Math.max(leftHeight, rightHeight);
  leftElement.style.height = maxHeight+"px";
  rightElement.style.height = maxHeight+"px";
}

window.onload = function() {
  setHeight();
};
window.onresize = function() {
  setHeight();
}
```

Comment: doesn't work, now the first div is larger than the second div

Comment: @Abhishek what exactly doesn't work? It seems to be working fine. See for yourself: https://jsfiddle.net/s6koa9n5/